# SQLAlchemy define relationship with a joined table

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlalchemy, foreign-keys

I'm trying to define a many-to-many relationship with a joined table, but I can't manage to accomplish it using sqlalchemy. Here's a example of my defined models:

```
class Bar(Model):
    __tablename__ = 'bar'

    bar_id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True)


class Foo(Model):
    __tablename__ = 'foo'

    foo_id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True)
    owner_id = Column(BigInteger, nullable=False, index=True)


class FooBar(Model):
    __tablename__ = 'foo_bar'

    foo_id = Column(ForeignKey('foo.foo_id'), nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    bar_id = Column(ForeignKey('bar.bar_id'), nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    amount = Column(Integer)

    foo = relationship('Foo')
    bar = relationship('Bar')


class EnhancedBar(Model):
    __tablename__ = 'enhanced_bar'

    bar_id = Column(ForeignKey('bar.bar_id'), primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    owner_id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True, nullable=False, index=True)

    bar = relationship('Bar', backref=backref('enhanced_bar', uselist=False))
    foos = relationship(
        'Foo', secondary='foo_bar',
        primaryjoin="and_(EnhancedBar.bar_id==FooBar.bar_id,"
                    "Foo.owner_id==EnhancedBar.owner_id)",
        backref=backref('enchanced_bars',
            primaryjoin="and_(EnhancedBar.bar_id==FooBar.bar_id, "
                        "Foo.owner_id==EnhancedBar.owner_id)")
    )
```

The EnhancedBar.foos relationship and its backref currently is working fine, but I'm not sure if it's the correct way to do this, because the above is issuing this query:

> ```
> SELECT *
> FROM foo, foo_bar 
> WHERE :param_1 = foo_bar.bar_id AND foo.ownwer_id = :param_2 AND foo.foo_id = foo_bar.foo_id
> ```

Actually I'm trying to issue the following query instead:

```
SELECT *
FROM foo JOIN foo_bar ON foo.foo_id = foo_bar.foo_id
WHERE foo.owner_id = :owner_id_param AND foo_bar.bar_id = :bar_id_param
```

But I can't find how to convert it to sqlalchemy language. Is there any specific notation I should be using to accomplish this?

Comment: `FROM foo JOIN foo_bar ON bar.bar_id = foo_bar.bar_id` makes no sense because `bar` does not appear in the list of tables.

Comment: @univerio Sorry, I wrote it wrong. I edited the question with the correct query

Comment: Those two queries are pretty much the same. The former is using an implicit join while the latter is using an explicit join.

Comment: I think I expressed myself poorly, in fact I'm wondering if there's something built-in on sqlalchemy to do this job without having to manually write the primaryjoin for the relationship and the backref, making it programmatically less verbose

Comment: You don't need to specify `primaryjoin` on the backref if you've specified it on the relationship. You do need to specify it on the relationship, because what you want is not the default.